# How to ignore specific fields in form in thymeleaf?

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm creating a form in thymeleaf that contains a file upload field that's not part of my model.
When I load the page, thymeleaf complains and throws `NotReadablePropertyException` for that field.

How can I get thymeleaf to ignore the fact that the field does not exist on the model?

Code:

```
<div class="form-group"
     th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('uploadFile')}? 'has-error'">
    <label class="col-sm-12 control-label" style="text-align: left; margin-bottom: 7px;">Upload Photo</label>
    <div class="col-sm-12" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
        <div class="fileinput fileinput-new input-group" data-provides="fileinput">
            <div class="form-control" data-trigger="fileinput">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file fileinput-exists"></i>
                <span class="fileinput-filename"></span>
            </div>
            <span class="input-group-addon btn btn-default btn-file">
                <span class="fileinput-new">Select file</span>
                <span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span>
                <input type="file" name="uploadFile" accept="image/*" required>
            </span>
            <a href="#" class="input-group-addon btn btn-default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remove</a>
        </div>
        <p id="error" style="position:absolute;color:#FF0000;margin-top:-7px"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'uploadFile' of bean class [bean.Library]: Bean property 'uploadFile' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error that you get is because of the line

```
th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('uploadFile')}
```

that expects a field expression as a parameter.

You can replace

```
th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('uploadFile')}
```

with

```
th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('*')}
```

where the has-error class will appear if there is an error with any of the fields.
Or you can even replace it with

```
th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('global')}
```

that is not associated with any specific field in the form.

Or alternatively, you can add the field (uploadFile) in the model as a transient attribute.